# Updating model objects in the database on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and for learning purposes I am trying to build my own site using the linkedn API to display my profile. The following is a a example of my code. To see the whole lot:

https://github.com/javiee/django-site

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name, self.last_name

class Education(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
school_name =  models.CharField(max_length=100) 
field_study =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
degree =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
start_date =  models.CharField(max_length=20)
end_date =  models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and views.py

```
  profile = Profile(first_name = content['firstName'], 
  last_name = content['lastName'],
  user = request.user)
  profile.save()

#Education model
content_educ = content['educations']['values']
for value in content_educ:
    education = Education(school_name = value['schoolName'],
            user = request.user,
            field_study = value['fieldOfStudy'],
            degree = value['degree'],
            start_date = value['startDate']['year'] ,
            end_date = value['endDate']['year'])
    education.save()
```

This all working but my problem is that everytime I check linkedn, the code saves all the objects again. What it would ideally do is to "update" fields based on the profile  when the .save() method is called. I have read the next link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

but I dont manage to get it working, perhaps foreigns keys are not properly set so any advise/help/tip will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your github project contains oauth token secrets. I sincerely hope these are not the real thing. If so, you might want to remove them from the repository and invalidate them with linkedin. Don't compromise your secret keys (even if only for testing)

Comment: That one is not valid, a new token is given everytime you allow access to the the application. The secret keys are somewhere else. Thanks for the advise though, I will remove it that comment cause is not needed,

Comment: I would still be interesting to know how long it takes till someone tries those invalid keys ;-)

Comment: It is been there for a while lol but you are right, I am sure someone will try. That token expires after a time and you need also log into linkedn account, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method:

```
Education.objects.update_or_create(
                   school_name=value['schoolName'],
                   user = request.user,
                   defaults={'field_study': value['fieldOfStudy'],
                             'degree': value['degree'],
                             'start_date': value['startDate']['year'] ,
                             'end_date': value['endDate']['year']})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're instantiating new Education instances in these lines:

```
    education = Education(school_name = value['schoolName'],
        user = request.user,
        field_study = value['fieldOfStudy'],
        degree = value['degree'],
        start_date = value['startDate']['year'] ,
        end_date = value['endDate']['year'])
```

When Django goes and tries to save these new instances (instances for which `id` is not yet defined), Django goes ahead and inserts the records rather than doing the update you want.

To do an update, you can either try to get the record, catching the `DoesNotExist` exception:

```
try:
    education = Education.objects.get(school_name=value['schoolName'],
        user=request.user,
        field_study=value['fieldOfStudy'],
        degree=value['degree'],
        start_date=value['startDate']['year'],
        end_date=value['endDate']['year'])
except Education.DoesNotExist:
    education = Education(school_name=value['schoolName'],
        user=request.user,
        field_study=value['fieldOfStudy'],
        degree=value['degree'],
        start_date=value['startDate']['year'],
        end_date=value['endDate']['year'])
```

then apply whatever updates you want/need.

Or you can use `get_or_create` to do the same:

```
(education, created) = Education.objects.get_or_create(school_name=value['schoolName'],
        user=request.user,
        field_study=value['fieldOfStudy'],
        degree=value['degree'],
        start_date=value['startDate']['year'],
        end_date=value['endDate']['year'])
```

If you don't want to look up your instances by all of those values (they're AND-ed), but want to initialize new instances with certain values, you should look up the `defaults` keyword for `get_or_create`.

Or you can use `update_or_create` as suggested by catavaran.

edit: Or, if you just want to do a straight update of a record without getting it (this also works with multiple objects at once), you can use `queryset.update`

```
Education.objects.filter(attribute=value, ...).update(attribute2=value2, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for you time, much appreciated. update_or_create did the job. And thanks for your second advise